# AjaxCart not deleting bundle items in Magento cartSidebar

Tags: magento-1.7, ajax

I have a strange problem that I have been trying to debug to a couple of hours now. I am using AjaxCart extension to add products to the shopping cart but for some reason I have an issue when trying to delete bundle items from the shopping cart sidebar I get a redirect to a blank page with the following:

```
{"hasOptions":true,"redirectUrl":"http://mysite.com/catalog/product/view/id/187/"}
```

Has anyone come across this before and know how to resolve it?

I can successfully remove items from shopping cart page using Ajax without any issues.

Comment: Well, that string is actualy JSON. That means that browser should have sent an AJAX request but somehow failed and sent a normal one. My guess is that you either have a Javascript error on that page, or your theme changed HTML so much, that Javascript can't react to click on that delete button. So I doubt anybody will be able to give you an answer without looking on your real website.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console of chrome or firebug in firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the error. It was to do with the opcheckout.js file. This line in particular:

```
 var updater = new Ajax.Updater('checkout-progress-wrapper', this.progressUrl, {method: 'get', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this)});
```

Needed to be:

```
var updater = new Ajax.Updater('checkout-progress-wrapper', this.progressUrl, {method: 'get', onComplete: function(){ajaxcart.updateMinicartEvent();}, onFailure:this.ajaxFailure.bind(this)});
```

And now the error is gone!

Thanks guys